# Comparing list and returning index

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, compare

```
List1 = ['3','1','2']
List2 = ['0','1','0']
List3 = ['string1','string2','string3']
```

I want to do

```
 if List1[i] > 3 and List2[i] = 0 # i = iterating through list1/2 at the same time and comparing them
     print(List3[i]) # i = being the index number found when the if statement is met

#expected output = 'string1'
```

Context : https://repl.it/@glasgowm1498/GreenyellowKnowingCommands

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-to-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel. Just use three lists instead of two.

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to accomplish. Your code comments are too ambiguous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use python's build in zip function [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip)

```
for item1, item2, item3 in zip(list1, list2, list3):
    if item1 == item2:
        print(item3)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks! I was using a method of that already but didn't realise you could use it for 3 items. Thanks for actually responding instead of moaning about formatting and downvoting like what seems prevalent in newbie questions here